# config database.php and env laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Pardon Me for asking noob question about laravel before.in laravel there are **config/database.php** and **.env file**. the code inside that file i assume is about database configuration such as connection matters. i want to know how laravel use that file.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is, but maybe for starters the config/database sets some configuration for database connections, and it uses a helper to optionally check your .env file for values for those configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .env file, you define the so called 'environmental settings' for your project. The docs will explain that.

The database config php file sets the settings for your database connection(s), in which the default connection refers to the database settings entered in the .env file. You can see that in the .php file in the `env()` function. This function receives settings from the .env file.

So if you just want to use one database connection, just type the fields in the .env file to your liking, and Laravel will do the rest. If you want to have multiple database connections, you should add these to the .php file. Please see the docs.

Comment: If you want to have multiple database connections, you should add these to the .php file - which 'these' to which .php file?